# Getting information about images/scripts/other files in WebView

Tags: android, webview

Id like to ask, whether there is a possibility to check the file sizes of certain data included in WebView.

Lets say I load a webpage, that contains few images, few JavaScript files etc.

Now what I need to do, is to get the size (in bytes) of those files.

If I understand it correctly, those files should be downloaded in the cache, so they are present. What I want to avoid is re-downloading those files just to get their size (I could manually parse the HTML and re-download them one by one).

Is this possible? Or any other way? I dont really care about displaying the page, it would happen in the background anyway, what I need are those data about files included in the web page.

Comment: or could I use Chromium (if, how?) or any other way?

Comment: If you want only download everything once and check the size, but not display, you can use `wget`, maybe?

Comment: I need to check the size of all files, not just the resulting web altogether.
If I understand correctly, wget does basically what HttpConnection ?

Comment: it also can download all linked files. but you can do it all by hand with http connection, of course

Comment: Thats what Iam talking about... I need to load the whole website (including potential AJAX files, so I cant download it manually, because I need JS to be interpreted), and then get info about the files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not 100% sure but i think this might work:

create a WebViewClient implementation for your WebView, in the implementation override the method: “ShouldInterceptRequest”, or the method “ShouldOverrideUrlLoading”.
These functions (especially the first one) give you the URL of any resource that the webview is trying to load (including images and scripts).
Keep a list of those urls, and make sure to return Null as the result of the function, so the webview will continue loading the page as usual.
At the end , you’ll have a final list of the URLs of ALL the resources the page needs (including stuff loaded in ajax, and stuff loaded from inside other urls) - you can then just download everything in the list using a HTTPConnection or whatever, and know the sizes.

Comment: thanks, I think I will use combination of the answers here. Thank you everybody. Unfortunately I can award the bounty only to one response.

Answer (score 0):

You can get just the header (including content-length) of any URL with "HEAD" http request method. By this way no data will be downloaded except the header.

Use `setRequestMethod("HEAD")` to do that.
e.g. :

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
String url = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b";
try {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    connection.connect();
    String contentLength = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Length");
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (ProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: wont that work only with web documents? e.g. I want to get size of a JPG/PNG image or javascript file, will it work too?

Comment: Yes, of course. It will work with all of the file types.

Comment: Ive ran to a problem, some files return "null" as their Content-Lenghth... any ideas why could it happen? When I open the file in my browser and get headers, I see normal content length...

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be helpful to you. Good luck!

From my experiences, I would do this: the *client will be notified by WebKit when there is some resource to be load/request. So you can keep URLs in "onLoadResource", and check requests of them in "shouldInterceptRequest", to see if there are duplicates. You can just return an empty WebResourceResponse to avoid data loading.

e.g.:

```
// webView is an instance of android.webkit.WebView
webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);


private WebViewClient mWebViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

        /**
         * Notify the host application of a resource request and allow the application
         * to return the data. 
         * If the return value is null, the WebView will continue to load the resource
         * as usual. 
         * Otherwise, the return response and data will be used. 
         * 
         * NOTE: This method is called by the network thread so clients should 
         *       exercise caution when accessing private data.
         * 
         * */
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
              ...  
              if (duplicate)
                  return NullWebResourceResponse(); 

              return null;
        }  

        /*
         * Notify the host application that the WebView will load the resource 
         * specified by the given url.
         */
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            //Log.d(LOGTAG, view.getClass().getSimpleName() + " - loading(" + url + ")...");
        };

    };
```

Comment: thanks, I think I will use combination of the answers here. Thank you everybody. Unfortunately I can award the bounty only to one response, and the response before you was first